# C# EF6-Lambda Expressions deep big-tree query improvement for efficiency and clean code

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, lambda

Hi there fellow coders,

I am looking to improve the following query.

We are using EF6 (CodeFirst) and C# Lambda Expressions, and Repository/Unit of Work patterns. Also, we needed to restrict the query in a way that we could inner-query the entities so that the query will only retrieve a subset of the joined data, and found this [DynamicSelectExtensions](https://github.com/thiscode/DynamicSelectExtensions) library that extends IQueryable and gives us a SelectIncluding statement so that we could do this.

## The Query

```
namespace Repositorios
{
    public class CanalDeComunicacionRepositorio: EFRepositorioDesactivable<CanalDeComunicacion>, ICanalDeComunicacionRepositorio
    {
        public CanalDeComunicacionRepositorio(DbContext context) : base(context) { }

        public IQueryable<CanalDeComunicacion> ConsultaParaLibreria()
        {
            return
                dbSet.Where(canalComunicacion=> canalComunicacion.FechaDesactivacion==null)
                .SelectIncluding(new List<Expression<Func<CanalDeComunicacion, object>>>()
                {
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Where(controlador=>controlador.FechaDesactivacion==null),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaPuertas.Where(puerta=>puerta.FechaDesactivacion==null)),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaPuertas.Select( puerta=>puerta.ListaLectoras.Where(lectora=>lectora.FechaDesactivacion==null))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Where(lectora=>lectora.FechaDesactivacion==null)),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaEventosExcluidos.Where(eventos=> eventos.FechaDesactivacion==null)),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Where(grupoLectora=>grupoLectora.FechaDesactivacion==null && grupoLectora.GrupoAcceso.FechaDesactivacion==null))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Where(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.FechaDesactivacion==null)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Select(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.GpoPadre)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Select(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.GpoPadre.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Where(listEmp => listEmp.FechaDesactivacion==null))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Select(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.GpoPadre.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(listEmp => listEmp.Persona))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Select(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.GpoPadre.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(listEmp => listEmp.Persona.ListaTarjetaPersona.Where(tarPer=>tarPer.FechaDesactivacion==null)))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Select(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.GpoPadre.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(listEmp => listEmp.Persona.ListaTarjetaPersona.Select(tarPer=>tarPer.Tarjeta)))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Select(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.GpoPadre.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(listEmp => listEmp.Persona.ListaTarjetaPersona.Select(tarPer=>tarPer.Tarjeta.ListaTiposTarjeta.Where(ltipo=>ltipo.FechaDesactivacion==null))))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeFeriados.Where(liferiado=> liferiado.FechaDesactivacion==null)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Where(lisEmpleado=> lisEmpleado.FechaDesactivacion==null)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeFeriados.Select(liferiado=> liferiado.Feriado)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrencia.Where(turno=>turno.FechaDesactivacion==null)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrencia.Select(turno=>turno.Turno).Select(turno=>turno)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrencia.Select(turno=>turno.Turno).Select(turno=>turno.ListaDiasHora.Where(lista=>lista.FechaDesactivacion==null))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrencia.Select(turno=>turno.Turno).Select(turno=>turno.ListaDiasHora.Select(lista=>lista.Dia))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(lisEmpleado=> lisEmpleado.Persona)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(grupoEmpleado=>grupoEmpleado.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrenciaEspecial.Where(listaTurnoRecurrencia=> listaTurnoRecurrencia.FechaDesactivacion==null))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(grupoEmpleado=>grupoEmpleado.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrenciaEspecial.Select(turno=>turno.Turno))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(grupoEmpleado=>grupoEmpleado.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrenciaEspecial.Select(turno=>turno.Turno.ListaDiasHora.Where(lista=>lista.FechaDesactivacion==null)))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(grupoEmpleado=>grupoEmpleado.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrenciaEspecial.Select(turno=>turno.Turno.ListaDiasHora.Select(lista=>lista.Dia)))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(lisEmpleado=> lisEmpleado.Persona.ListaTarjetaPersona.Where(lisTarjeta=>lisTarjeta.FechaDesactivacion==null))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(lisEmpleado=> lisEmpleado.Persona.ListaTarjetaPersona.Select(lisTarjeta=>lisTarjeta.Tarjeta))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(lisEmpleado=> lisEmpleado.Persona.ListaTarjetaPersona.Select(lisTarjeta=>lisTarjeta.Tarjeta.ListaTiposTarjeta.Where(list=>list.FechaDesactivacion==null)))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaTiposTarjeta.Where(list=>list.FechaDesactivacion==null)))
                }).AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

The query just works as of right now, but it is a very slow query, and also the code is pretty ugly and long and nested.

## The Model

This is the data model for the entities involved in the query. As you can see, we need to join a lot of tables and traverse the tree to get all the data we need.
(I tried to post the image but I need 10 reputation to post it.) So, here is the link to it: [Data Model](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1180710/DataModel.png)

If you need any more info please be sure to let me know.
Any input will be greately appreciated, so I thank you in advanced.

Comment: OMG. What a query... What are you actually trying to retrieve from DB?

Comment: We are trying to retrieve a big object tree to feed an external library that cannot access our database and needs all of that data.

Comment: @beto_ve Have you considered turning this into an indexed view in your DB and creating a type to represent this aggregation of data? EF6 is able to interface with database views. That way you can fine tune the query in native SQL, and your code only needs to worry about where to send the neatly packaged result, instead of doing complicated set logic.

Comment: You might want to check out [CodeReview.Stack](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).